# low voltage pin in Keil (ARM) debuging?

Tags: gpio, port

I am going to work with one TFT LCD 2'8 (ILI9325 Driver) with STM32F103RE ARM MCU.  So I have one example program in Mikroc for ARM ( Microelectronica Co), which is working good, you could download the code:

[ili9325-tft-touch-screen](https://libstock.mikroe.com/projects/view/1797/ili9325-tft-touch-screen-display-demo-with-stm32)

I have changed the code to work in Keil v5.14.  My code is here:

[ili9325-tft-touch-screen in Keil](https://www.4shared.com/s/f90XITXc1da)

And it's conection here:

[image: Is's Connections Prots and Data]

As you can see in the debugging mode after `GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);` ( port B is used as data port "B0-B15" -> "D1-D17" Of LCD) in line 197 I added this :

```
GPIOB->ODR=0xFFFFFFFF;
```

this pic:

[image: Debugging mode]

But when I reach this line in debugging the pin_4 AND pin_3 of ports have had a little voltage and current on it and don't set to 1 logic when the other pins of this port become high, you can see here:

[image]

and by running this code :

```
GPIOB->ODR=0x00000000;
```

pin_4 AND Pin_3  don't become off completely, as you can see in this picture

[image]

but the other pins of port B become one like this:

[image]

and completely off.

So what do you think?

Comment: What is connected to these pins? We need to see a schematic of the connections. Also, provide a schematic of whatever you are sticking in there to check the logic level.

Comment: port B is used for data port connection to D1-D17 in LCD TFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, pins PB3 and PB4 are used for the JTAG functions TDO and TRST. The state of `GPIOB->ODR` doesn't modify this behavior.

These pins aren't the only ones in PORTB with assigned uses, either -- PB2 is BOOT1, so trying to use it as an output will cause problems as well. If you want to use an entire port as a 16-bit parallel output, you will need to use another port -- PORTC is probably your best option on the STM32F103RC. (PC14 and PC15 have some caveats, as they are used for the LSE oscillator, but the rest of the pins should be free.)

You can disable this by setting `AFIO_MAPR->SWJ_CFG` to `AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG_JTAGDISABLE` or `AFIO_MAPR_SWJ_CFG_DISABLE`. (This is documented in the "Debug Support" chapter of the STM32F1 reference manual.) However, since you're using a JTAG probe, this will cause you to lose debug connectivity.

Comment: the connection is the same with Mikroc Pro For ARM and Keil programs but in Mikroc Pro For ARM, this is working but in the Keil not !!!! so without debugging and in the normal operation, I see this floating voltage on the pin4 AND Pin3 Of port B in Keil which in Mikroc Pro For ARM don't happen.

Comment: I have added "GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_Remap_SWJ_JTAGDisable, ENABLE);" but still have the problem.!!!

Comment: i changed portB to Porta as data port and it's working. Thanks a lot